# Type casting in a generic swift function

Tags: swift, generics

Supposing I have a UICollectionViewCell and a UITableViewCell with identical properties. Rather than have two functions which populate those cells, could I have a generic that takes something  , determine what that was and then cast it to the correct thing to perform actions on it before returning?

my thinking is:

```
func setUpCell<T>(event: Event, cell:T) -> T {

    // figure out what T is and cast it
    cell.event.bar = event.bar
    return cell

}
```

is this a good way of avoiding large amounts of code duplication?

Comment: More information is needed, what class is foo? Where do you have the properties `seperatorInset`, `event`, `bar` defined? You need to expand your example.

Comment: What is `foo`? If you want to perform the same operations on two different types, they will have to share some interface, e.g. adopt the same protocol, be subclasses of the same superclass etc.

Comment: foo is nothing, its just an example, what I have is a UITableViewCell and UICollectionViewCell subclasses with that have the same properties and need to be set much in the same way.  I could write two separate functions but thought generics might be some other way of doing it

Comment: So protocols would be the way to go perhaps will look into how that might be implemented

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this match what you were thinking?

```
import UIKit

struct Event {
  var bar:Int = 0
}

// Protocol to group common additions
protocol ViewCellAdditions {
  init()
  var separatorInset:Int { get set }
  var event:Event { get set}
}

// Generic function to work on any class that adopts ViewCellAdditions
func setUpCell<T: ViewCellAdditions>(event: Event, cell:T, foo:Int) -> T {
  var newCell = T()
  newCell.separatorInset = foo
  newCell.event.bar = event.bar
  return newCell
}

// Class that adopts ViewCellAdditions
class NewCellClass: ViewCellAdditions {
  required init() {}
  var separatorInset:Int = 10
  var event:Event = Event()
}

// How to use it
let aCell = NewCellClass()
let aEvent = Event()
let newCell = setUpCell(aEvent, cell: aCell, foo: 5)
```

Comment: This looks good also, supposing I wanted to set up a function on ViewCellAdditions called displayView() that required access to the cells View, I assume I could still call this from setUpCell as normal

Comment: You can't do that because `UIView` is a class, not a property. Instead what you would do is either extend `UIView` to conform to the property or have your new class inherit from `UIView` and the new property. The latter is probably best.

Answer (score 3):

Given your model type

```
struct Event {
    let title: String
    let desc: String
}
```

define this protocol

```
protocol EventCell: class {
    var id: String? { get set }
    var desc: String? { get set }
}
```

Now conform your `UITabelViewCell` and `UICollectionViewCell` to it

```
class TableCell: UITableViewController, EventCell {
    var id: String?
    var desc: String?
}

class CollectionCell: UICollectionViewCell, EventCell {
    var id: String?
    var desc: String?
}
```

And finally define this extension

```
extension EventCell {
    func populate(event:Event) {
        self.id = event.id
        self.desc = event.desc
    }
}
```

That's it. Now both your cells (`UITabelViewCell` and `UICollectionViewCell`) have the `populate` method!

Comment: This seems nice I would like to try this, there are a few functions on the cells that populate the view so as EVentCell has no access to the view those operations would need to be kept on their separate respective classes I assume